# multiple checkboxes overwrite one another in react native

Tags: react-native, checkbox

I have a list of conditions i need  check boxes next to.  I have been able to do this, but now once a second checkmark is introduced , the first disappears. My code is as follows:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
import styles from './Styles';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'


export default class Symptoms extends React.Component {
state = {
    checkedId: 'false',
    checkboxes: [
        {id: 1, title: "Fever"},
        {id: 2, title: "Headache"},
     ]
  }

  handleCheck = (checkedId) => {
    this.setState({checkedId})
  }

render() {
    const { checkboxes, checkedId } = this.state

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: styles.scrollStyle.backgroundColor, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

        <View>
                {checkboxes.map(checkbox => (
                    <CheckBox
                    center
                    iconRight
                    checkedIcon='check-circle-o'
                    uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
                    checkedColor='#122fae'
                    uncheckedColor='#122fae'
                    key={checkbox.id}
                    title={checkbox.title}
                    checked={checkbox.id == checkedId}
                    onPress={() => this.handleCheck(checkbox.id)}

                    />
                ))}
        </View>
     </View>
  );
}
```

}

Comment: Isn't the behavior here actually a radio button? You can only check one things, right? You might want to take a look at [ButtonGroup](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button_group.html)

Comment: @BenKane thanks, yes this is functioning as a radio button.  but i don't want that, I need to select more than one option.  maybe the ButtonGroup documentation can help

Comment: You have `checked={checkbox.id == checkedId}` and you change the `checkedId` to match whatever the last checkbox the user checked is. By definition with that only one can be checked. If you want multiple checkboxes to be able to be checked, add an `isChecked` boolean to each checkbox object and get rid of `checkedId`

Comment: @BenKane  Thank you for the hint.  I'm just really not getting anywhere, now both boxes get marked when only one is clicked on.              
    state = {
        checkboxes: [
            {id: 1, isChecked: 'false',title: "Fever"},
            {id: 2, isChecked: 'false',title: "Headache"},
         ]
      }                                                                      const { checkboxes} = this.state            
 checked={this.state.isChecked}
                        onPress={() =>   this.setState(({ isChecked }) => ({isChecked: !isChecked}

Comment: Can you post your updated code?

Comment: @BenKane i tried to edit my post with the updated code but but could not do so.  I put the relevant lines in my previous comment

Comment: I'll leave an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need each checkbox to track whether or not it's checked. Right now you're only tracking what the latest check was with `checkId`. I'd suggest removing `checkId` altogether and tracking in state whether a checkbox is checked or not by its id. You can also pull out the checkbox definition into its own constant since it doesn't change, rather than recreate it on every render.

Something like this might work (completely untested, sorry, but hopefully it's a start):

```js
const checkboxes = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Fever' },
  { id: 2, title: 'Headache' }
]

const Symptoms = () => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState({});

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: styles.scrollStyle.backgroundColor, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <View>
        {checkboxes.map(checkbox => {
          const isChecked = checked[checkbox.id];

          return (
            <CheckBox
              center
              iconRight
              checkedIcon='check-circle-o'
              uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
              checkedColor='#122fae'
              uncheckedColor='#122fae'
              key={checkbox.id}
              title={checkbox.title}
              checked={isChecked === true}
              onPress={() => setChecked({...checked, [checkbox.id]: !isChecked})} />
          ));
        }}
      </View>
    </View>
 );
}

export default Symptoms;
```

Comment: i tried messing with what you gave me to no avail unfortunately. also, checkbox.id in the onPress function gives an error because of the period in it.  not sure the reasoning of why it doesn't take that type

Comment: @swimmerfish5 oops that should have been `[checkbox.id]` in the `onPress`. That will make the key be the checkbox id. I edited, can you try again?

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have questions on how any of it is working